# Decentralized Exchange on Ethereum

Tags: exchanges

I know this was asked several times on stackexchange, but after I see there are some alternatives for Ethereum Decentralized Exchange, but none seems to be stable.

I know about http://etherex.github.io/etherex and https://oasisdex.com. Is there anything else which is usable. How stable is EtherEx now?